# What is the time complexity of APPEND to standard internal table in ABAP?

Tags: time-complexity, abap

What is the time complexity of APPEND to standard internal table in ABAP?

Code example:

```
REPORT zz_complexity_1.

DATA: lt_tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string.

APPEND 'a sample text' INTO lt_tab.
```

I have implemented a stack using an internal table. I would like to be sure that I understand the time complexity of my stack implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I would expect it to be the same as appending to an [ArrayList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

This would mean that its time complexity would be Θ(1) [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Performance). *Amortized* constant time means that some operations will take longer than constant time, but those are infrequent enough to not sway how we measure it. If we `append` a trillion items, it would be very close, but not exactly, constant time.

When a standard table is defined, we do not know how many rows it will contain, so it may only allocate enough memory to hold *X* rows. Once *X* rows are in the table, the next `append` operation will allocate an additional *X* rows (assuming doubling every time, as this is how most languages work). Once all of this new memory is allocated, the next `append` will allocate space in memory for *2X* rows, then *4X*, then *8X*, etc. Consequently, the earlier allocations are more often but not as big, while later on the allocations are few and far between but request larger chunks of memory.

[image: Amortized Push Operations]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis#Dynamic_Array